# Having trouble toggling the Text on a button as well as saving that state

Tags: java, android

I am having trouble toggling the text on a button and saving it at the time.
My code is as followed

```
    switch(input_btn.getText())
    {
       case "A": input_btn.setText("B");break;
       case "B": input_btn.setText("A");break;
    }
```

I have a button that all it does is toggle the text on it from A to B

This code is all you need for toggling a button however My issue is I am unsure what I would do to save the text for the next time it opens.
If I save it after the switch statement lets just say that I want to Save A.
then A would be saved and it will be returned just before the switch statement but because of my switch statement I would set the text to B.

This interested me since I can not actually find a way to get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would to be to use SharedPreferences.

Try something like this:

```
private void setInputButtonText(String value){
    input_btn.setText(value);

    //Save input text in SharedPreferences
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
    edit.putString("YourKeyNameHere", value);
    boolean success = edit.commit();
    // you can do something with success if you need

}
```

Then add this:

```
private void getLastInputButtonText(){
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String lastInput = pref.getString("YourKeyNameHere");

    if(!lastInput.isEmpty()){
        input_btn.setText(lastInput);
    }
    //Else do what ever you need to do
}
```

Call `getLastInputButtonText()` from within `onCreate()`.

Now you can call from wherever you were calling it before:

```
String inputBtnText = input_btn.getText().toString();
switch(inputBtnText)
    {
       case "A": 
            setInputButtonText("B");
            break;
       case "B": 
            setInputButtonText("A");
            break;
    }
```